# Shift operation in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

Is it possible to shift `0`s as you can shift `1`s in shifting operation in C?

Something like this

```
for (i=0; i<32; i++) {
    if (data & 0x01) { 
        data |= (1<<i);
    }
    else { 
        data &=~ (0<<i);
    }
}
```

I'm checking if some bits are set and depending on that I'm storing `0`s or `1`s in new variable, shifting every bit to left.

Comment: Shifting is "shifting" both zeros and ones.

Comment: First of all, the `<` operator is the less-than comparison operator. Secondly, if you want to *clear* bits then use the bitwise AND (`&`) and complement (`~`) operators.

Comment: why to clear? I'm just masking (checking) required bits and storing them in new variable with help of shift operator

Comment: so to set bit I need to use |= operator combination and to clear need to use &= ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift operations are performed using a CPU register.  The register consists of a number of bits (8, 16 and 32 are common, and you appear to have a 32 CPU), which in combination can be interpreted as a decimal value.

In your example you use the value 1.  The C language allows the value one to be represented in several ways, all of which result in the same content of the CPU register:

```
decimal      hexadecimal  binary
1            0x00000001   0b00000000000000000000000000000001
3713883835   0xDD5D5EBB   0b11011101010111010101111010111011
```

(In all cases leading `0`s can be omitted.)

In the binary representation, all of the CPU register bit values are specified.  As you can see, this includes 0s as well as 1s.  So when you place the value 1 in a register and perform a left shift using the `<<` operator, the content of the entire register will be shifted left by one bit, with a 0 being placed in to the least significant bit.

In your code the value assigned to data will follow this pattern:

```
i = 0,  data = 0x00000000000000000000000000000001
i = 1,  data = 0x00000000000000000000000000000010
i = 2,  data = 0x00000000000000000000000000000100
etc.
i = 30, data = 0x01000000000000000000000000000000
i = 31, data = 0x10000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you were to use a different value than 1 to shift, you would of course end up with a different pattern, but it would follow the same rules.  I.e.  all of the bits get shifted, regardless of whether they hold a 1 or a 0.

```
for(i=0;i<32;i++)
{
    data = (165 << i) // 165 = 0xA5 = 0b10100101
}

Produces:
i = 0,  data = 0x00000000000000000000000010100101
i = 1,  data = 0x00000000000000000000000101001010
i = 2,  data = 0x00000000000000000000001010010100
etc.
i = 28, data = 0x10100000000000000000000000000000
i = 29, data = 0x01000000000000000000000000000000
i = 30, data = 0x10000000000000000000000000000000
i = 31, data = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Note how the pattern disappears towards the end as the most significant bits get shifted out of the register.

The same rules hold for doing right shifts using the `>>` operator, except that the bits move from most significant towards least significant.

(Some CPUs also have Rotate and other wonderful bit manipulation instructions.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't shift `0` or `1`, you shift the bit values, be it either `0` or `1`. In other words, you Shift the *bit positions*, regardless of the *value* stored in them.

From `C11` standard, chapter §6.5.7. , *Bitwise shift operators*

> The result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros.

It is just like that, in case of `1`s, the shifting is *visible*.

That said, `<` is ***not*** a bit-shift operator (as in your code), `<<` is.

Comment: If I shift variable, whether it will keep that value in the future operations?

Comment: @Lazar what is that future operation? See, the `>>` produces the _shifted value_. If you want to store the value, you've to assign the _shifted_ value back to the variable itself. Just like, doing `i+1` does not change `i`, but `i = i + 1` does.

Comment: So, to obtain a new variable value we need to assign that value in new or existing variable on which operation is applied. When In/decrementing or shifting variables, value of variable doesn't change until it is assigned to itself, like you said for i.

Comment: How to set some bits but in variable, but not affecting the other bits already stored in it?

Comment: @Lazar 1) yes 2) that is what bitwise operators are meant for.

Answer (score 2):

`<<` (not `<`!) does not shift one bit. It shifts the whole number. When you say `1<<5`, it is shifting `0000000000000001` five places left (given a 16-bit value), which gives `0000000000100000`. `0<<5` is shifting `0000000000000000` five places left, which results in `0000000000000000` (i.e. same value). The other bits are not indeterminate: you can't shift a single bit (I assume you want something like `??????????1?????` and `??????????0?????`, but numbers don't work like that.)

This looks like a typical XY-problem. You likely want to use `data` to switch on or switch off a bit in something else? Ask about *that*. (EDIT: As said by Joachim Pileborg in question comments.)

Answer (score 1):

The good news is - you're way over-thinking it.

Take the whole number, say: `01011011`.

Shift it left 1: `10110110`.

The 'whole thing' shifts together; zeroes are shifted into the LSB. In the case of right-shifting, it's zeroes again for unsigned, or implementation-defined for signed numbers:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

([S6.5.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1336.pdf))

Which means right-shifting a signed number may result in either an arithmetic shift, or a logical shift.

---

If you want to shift `1`s in to the low end, instead of `0`s, just OR with a bit-mask for the number of places you shifted.